# Kornshell variable definition: What is ?FOO?

Tags: shell

I found a line of code in a kornshell script:

```
foo=`basename ?BAR?`
```

What does the question marks mean?

Thank you

Comment: `basename` is used to detect the full path of script.

Comment: Thanks. What is ?BAR? doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
touch BAR ABAR ABARZ
ls ?BAR?
ABARZ
```

`?` is normally a shell wildcard char that matches 1 character, and that 1 character position must be in use,  as shown in the example above. It's like a 1-char version of '*', match 1 char (that must be there). Notice that if you change to

```
ls ?BAR*
```

You get output like

```
ABAR  ABARZ
```

Your code shows the same behavior

```
foo=$(basename ?BAR?)
echo $foo
ABARZ
```

Does that make sense? Not really, but given the small context you have given the other possible interpretation is that the original script writer is using `?BAR?` as a place-holder and  telling you  "change this to a real/meaningful value".

Other may have other ideas.

IHTH

Comment: This is not a place-holder because it is in running productive scripts.

Comment: ok, well like I said, just processing filenames as described doesn't make sense to me, but maybe you have more context and can see something in how this script is working that makes sense. Maybe it's just a temp file with version letters front and back?

Comment: Thank you. More useful context is not visible in this script, it's just processing files, whose filenames I don't know . But I think that's exactly what it does. Processing files like 0BAR1 0BAR2... Thank you